# NGINX Reverse Proxy not working

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

I am linking docker containers to an NGINX container with the following configuration. **node1 resolved to an entry in **/etc/hosts is all you really need to know for this part**

```
worker_processes 4;
events { worker_connections 1024; }


http {    

    upstream node_app {
          server node1:8080;
    }

    server {
          listen 80;

          location / {
            proxy_pass http://node_app;
          }
    }
 }
```

When I hit **http://{host-machine-ip}** I get the right page I am expecting HOWEVER, if I change the **location /** to **location /service** like the following it does not work and it returns with a 404.

```
worker_processes 4;
events { worker_connections 1024; }


http {    

    upstream node_app {
          server node1:8080;
    }

    server {
          listen 80;

          location /service {
            proxy_pass http://node_app;
          }
    }
 }
```

For more background on the setup, I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331760/nginx-reverse-proxy-failing-with-linked-docker-containers/31333792?noredirect=1#comment50676046_31333792)