# nginx docker container: 502 bad gateway response

Tags: nginx, docker

I've a service listening to 8080 port. This one is not a container.

Then, I've created a nginx container using official image:

```
docker run --name nginx -d -v /root/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d -p 443:443 -p 80:80 nginx
```

After all:

```
# netstat -tupln | grep 443
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      3482/docker-proxy
# netstat -tupln | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3489/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1009/java
```

Nginx configuration is:

```
upstream eighty {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name eighty.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass                        http://eighty;
    }
}
```

I've checked I'm able to connect with with this server with `# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080`

```
 <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh'
 content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body
 style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
 ...
```

It seems running well, however, when I'm trying to access using my browser, nginx tells bt a 502 bad gateway response.

I'm figuring out it can be a problem related with the visibility between a open by a non-containerized process and a container. Can I container stablish connection to a port open by other non-container process?

**EDIT**

Logs where `upstream { server 127.0.0.1:8080; }`:

```
2016/07/13 09:06:53 [error] 5#5: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 62.57.217.25, server: eighty.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "eighty.domain.com"
62.57.217.25 - - [13/Jul/2016:09:06:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0" "-"
```

Logs where `upstream { server 0.0.0.0:8080; }`:

```
62.57.217.25 - - [13/Jul/2016:09:00:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0" "-" 2016/07/13 09:00:30 [error] 5#5: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
62.57.217.25, server: eighty.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/", host: "eighty.domain.com" 2016/07/13 09:00:32 [error] 5#5: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 62.57.217.25, server: eighty.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/", host: "eighty.domain.com"
62.57.217.25 - - [13/Jul/2016:09:00:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0" "-"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a quick guess, could it be due to the server address? Can you try and change it from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0? If it's not the case then some other applicative failure occurs, check the logs or post them and I'll try to see what's the matter, also add the port (8080) to `http://eighty` at the `proxy_pass` line.

Comment: I've just added logs on post right now.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `proxy_pass` as well?

Comment: Yes, I've set `proxy_pass` to `http://0.0.0.0:8080`. The same problem...

Comment: I see, the logs show you are using IPv6, can you try and change it to IPv4?

Comment: By default it set up using IPv6. I've absolutly no idea how to change it. What do I need to change? docker behaviour or OS behaviour? However, I've performed a `curl http:127.0.0.1:8080` and it responds me well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117182/discussion-between-yaron-and-jordi).

Comment: For me the fix was to add a trailing slash to the proxy_pass directive, as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/31357655

Comment: were you using docker on linux or windows?

Comment: probably you missed the `/` after your proxy_pass address!

Answer (score 164):

### The Problem

Localhost is a bit tricky when it comes to containers. Within a docker container, localhost points to the container itself.
This means, with an upstream like this:

```
upstream foo{
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

or

```
upstream foo{
  server 0.0.0.0:8080;
}
```

you are telling nginx to pass your request to the local host.
But in the context of a docker-container, localhost (and the corresponding ip addresses) are pointing to the container itself:

[image]

by addressing 127.0.0.1 you will never reach your host machine, if your container is not on the host network.

### Solutions

#### Host Networking

You can choose to run nginx on the same network as your host:

```
docker run --name nginx -d -v /root/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d --net=host nginx
```

Note that you do not need to expose any ports in this case.

This works though you lose the benefit of docker networking. If you have multiple containers that should communicate through the docker network, this approach can be a problem. If you just want to deploy nginx with docker and do not want to use any advanced docker network features, this approach is fine.

#### Access the hosts remote IP Address

Another approach is to reconfigure your nginx upstream directive to directly connect to your host machine by adding its remote IP address:

```
upstream foo{
  //insert your hosts ip here
  server 192.168.99.100:8080;
}
```

The container will now go through the network stack and resolve your host correctly:

[image]

You can also use your DNS name if you have one. Make sure docker knows about your DNS server.

Comment: Excellent & straight answer. Saved me a lot of time

Comment: How would I connect nginx to a docker container if both are running on kubernetes? As far as I understand it, there is no fixed IP, I could point nginx at as there could be multiple instances of the container running at the same time.

Comment: Found an answer to my kubernetes question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103242/nginx-config-for-django-app-in-kubernetes-cluster

Comment: My request to 192.168.*.* keeps timing out

Comment: for docker-compose you can use network_mode: "host"

Comment: @Aleem do you could share example using network_mode  in gist template docke-compose?  https://gist.github.com/jonathasborges1/592b79245c2b8c686f1cb4b79cf4aff0

Answer (score 12):

For me helped this line of code `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`

```
server {
   listen            80;
   server_name  localhost;
location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://myserver;
}
```

Comment: I spent days trying to figure how why networking is so slow between my nginx container&django container on docker-compose bridge network. This has really been a lifesaver for me. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find any relevant documentation for `proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;`

Answer (score 12):

Just to complete other answers, I'm using mac for development and using host.docker.internal directly on upstream worked for me and no need to pass the host remote IP address. Here is config of the proxy nginx:

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    upstream app1 {
        server host.docker.internal:81;
    }

    upstream app1 {
        server host.docker.internal:82;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1.com;
    
        location / {
          proxy_pass    http://app1;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app2.com;
    
        location / {
          proxy_pass    http://app2;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I used different ports for different apps behind the nginx proxy. I used port 81 for the app1 and port 82 for the app2 and both app1 and app2 have their own nginx containers:

For app1:

```
docker run --name nginx -d -p 81:80 nginx
```

For app2:

```
docker run --name nginx -d -p 82:80 nginx
```

Also, please refer to this link for more details:
[docker doc for mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is configure `proxy_pass` that from `container` perspective the adress will be pointing to your real host.

To get `host` address from container perspective you can do as following on Windows with docker `18.03` (or more recent):

Run bash on container from host where image name is `nginx` (works on `Alpine Linux distribution`):

```
 docker run -it nginx /bin/ash
```

Then run inside container

```
/ # nslookup host.docker.internal

Name:      host.docker.internal
Address 1: 192.168.65.2
```

`192.168.65.2` is the host's IP - not the bridge IP like in `spinus` accepted answer.

I am using here [host.docker.internal](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-windows):

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker for Windows.

Then you can change `nginx` config to:
`proxy_pass   http://192.168.65.2:{your_app_port};`

and it should work fine.

Remember to provide the same `port` as your local application runs with.

Comment: @pini-cheyni (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1773972/pini-cheyni) `bin/ash` does exist - you can read about it for example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44912/are-dash-ash-and-sh-script-100-compatible

This is not typo of `bash` or `sh`.

Comment: you are right, on my Debian systems it doesn't exist so I thought it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

## nginx.sh

```
ip=$(ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | head -n 1)

docker run --name nginx --add-host="host:${ip}" -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

## nginx.conf

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://host:8080/;
}
```

It‘s works for me

Answer (score 1):

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {

    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket

    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}


location / {

        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /path/to/your/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
```

**complete reference**: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: Please improve your question. Code + link answers are rarely suitable. Please add an additional explanation to your question as well. I have formatted the part of your answer I think was code, please check/change it to what you originally intended. I am not downvoting at this moment, but if you do not make these changes it will certainly be flagged as very low quality :(

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but in my case it is because I was directing https traffic (from the load balancer - ALB) to http. Changing the protocol of the target group to http resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

> I've checked I'm able to connect with with this server with # curl http://127.0.0.1:8080

In my case I would get a `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` error when doing that, and it turned out to be a firewall issue. I disabled the firewall and it worked.

I got a clue by curling the docker IP, which properly output the html homepage.

```
sudo ip addr show docker0
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:a9:60:8e:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

curl 172.17.0.1:5870
```

Before disabling firewall:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5870
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

curl 0.0.0.0:5870
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

After: I get the HTML page output.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and it turned out to be an issue with the docker container not starting up due to a permissions issue.

In my case running

```
docker-compose ps
```

showed that the container had not started and exited with status 1. Turns out the permissions had been lost in migrating to a new machine. Adjusting the permissions to a know staff user on the parent directory fixed the problem for me and I was then able to start docker service where as previously I was getting

```
nginx_1_c18a7f6f7d6d | chown: /var/www/html: Operation not permitted
```