# connection between two docker container

Tags: docker, containers

in this question, I refer to the answer to the following question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329040/translate-vagrant-statements-in-docker-statements/52331641#52331641).I have two docker container. In one I have my database and in the other a jenkins server. The latter was already created and is running. My docker container for my database is created as follows:

```
docker run -d --name postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432  postgres:10.4-alpine
```

Then I created a nework via

```
docker network create --driver=bridge postgres_jenkins_network
```

and put both container in this network with

```
docker network connect postgres_jenkins_network postgres
docker network connect postgres_jenkins_network jenkins
```

Unfortunately, my jenkins is not able to connect to my postgres database, since I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused
```

My Application which is tested by jenkins has the following application properties and yml data:

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

**application.yml**

```
  spring:
  profiles: dev

  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: user
    password: password

server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /mep
  port: 9000
```

It seems, that my application get no access to my database but I have no idea why this is the case.

Thanks for any help
Matthias

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx docker container: 502 bad gateway response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346847/nginx-docker-container-502-bad-gateway-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have to use **postgres** instead of **localhost** in the url in your *application.yml* file: `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres`
Because you want to connect to your postgres database server which runs in the container with the name **postgres**.