# Nginx upstream server values when serving an API using docker-compose and kubernetes

Tags: django, docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker-compose and kubernetes as two different solutions to setup a Django API served by Gunicorn (as the web server) and Nginx (as the reverse proxy). Here are the key files:

default.tmpl (nginx) - this is converted to default.conf when the environment variable is filled in:

```
upstream api {
    server ${UPSTREAM_SERVER};
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    location /staticfiles {
        alias /app/static/;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api-gunicorn:
    build: ./api
    command: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app

  api-proxy:
    build: ./api-proxy
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.tmpl > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    environment:
      - UPSTREAM_SERVER=api-gunicorn:8000
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./api/static:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - api-gunicorn
```

api-deployment.yaml (kubernetes):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-myapp-api-proxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp-api-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp-api-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp-api-gunicorn
          image: "helm-django_api-gunicorn:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          command:
            - "/bin/bash"
          args:
            - "-c"
            - "gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application"
        - name: myapp-api-proxy
          image: "helm-django_api-proxy:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          command:
            - "/bin/bash"
          args:
            - "-c"
            - "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.tmpl > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
          env:
            - name: UPSTREAM_SERVER
              value: 127.0.0.1:8000
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /app/static
              name: api-static-assets-on-host-mount
      volumes:
        - name: api-static-assets-on-host-mount
          hostPath:
            path: /Users/jonathan.metz/repos/personal/code-demos/kubernetes-demo/helm-django/api/static
```

My question involves the `UPSTREAM_SERVER` environment variable.

For `docker-compose.yaml`, the following values have worked for me:

- Setting it to the name of the gunicorn service and the port it's running on (in this case `api-gunicorn:8000`). This is the best way to do it (and how I've done it in the docker-compose file above) because I don't need to expose the `8000` port to the host machine.
- Setting it to `MY_IP_ADDRESS:8000` as [described in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346847/nginx-docker-container-502-bad-gateway-response). This method requires me to expose the `8000` port, which is not ideal.

For `api-deployment.yaml`, only the following value has worked for me:

- Setting it to `localhost:8000`. [Inside of a pod, all containers can communicate using localhost](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#networking).

Are there any other values for `UPSTREAM_SERVER` that work here, especially in the kubernetes file? I feel like I should be able to point to the container's name and that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to target container *myapp-api-gunicorn* but this will expose it  outside of the `pod`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-gunicorn-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp-api-proxy
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

You might also use [hostname and subdomain fields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods) inside a `pod` to take advantage of FQDN.

> Currently when a pod is created, its hostname is the Pod’s  `metadata.name`  value.
>
> The Pod spec has an optional  `hostname`  field, which can be used to specify the Pod’s hostname. When specified, it takes precedence over the Pod’s name to be the hostname of the pod. For example, given a Pod with  `hostname`  set to “`my-host`”, the Pod will have its hostname set to “`my-host`”.
>
> The Pod spec also has an optional  `subdomain`  field which can be used to specify its subdomain. For example, a Pod with  `hostname`  set to “`foo`”, and  `subdomain`  set to “`bar`”, in namespace “`my-namespace`”, will have the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) “`foo.bar.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`”.

Also here is a nice article from [Mirantis](https://www.mirantis.com/) which talks about [exposing multiple containers in a pod](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/)