# nginx proxy_pass return 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: spring, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm building nginx for reverse_proxy with Spring and Docker

Here is my configuration.

**nginx.conf**

```
user  proxy;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    include /home/wertkey/nginx/conf/conf.d/*.conf;

    client_max_body_size 200M;
    client_header_buffer_size  48k;

    server {
        listen       7070 default_server;
        listen       [::]:7070 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

**conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 7070;
    server_name something.com;

    proxy_connect_timeout   900s;
    proxy_send_timeout      900s;
    proxy_read_timeout      900s;
    send_timeout            900s;

    location ^~ /editor/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        rewrite ^/editor/(/.*)$ $1 break;
    }
}
```

**docker**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
a6a6a98a25a9        editor       "/bin/sh -c /usr/l..."   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp   editor
```

My spring server is running at 7070 port.
I want to be this way.

1. request something.com:7070/api
2. nginx proxy_pass to 8081
3. and docker 8081 -> 8080

But response always return 502 Bad Gateway

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try what is suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47663730/353765): add `--net=host` to the `docker` command line.